# Is it possible to connect to another PC with python socket by using his public IPV4 or his pc name?

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I'm trying to create an sort of Pokémon online game in python and I wanted to know if it is possible to the server to bind to his own address for other clients can connect to him using his public ipv4 or his pc name even if they're not on the same network, thanks.

I tried by typing my public ipv4 in the server.bind line and same for the client.connect but nothing happened is there any other solutions?